# Reference to study moduli spaces

Tags: algebraic-geometry, differential-geometry, reference-request

I would like to know about references where the problem of finding the infinitesimal deformations of a given geometric structure, and obtaining the corresponding (elliptic?) complex parametrizing the deformations of the structure and its obstructions etc etc is explained in detail.

Thanks.

Comment: What kinds of structure do you have in mind?

Comment: For example, complex structures on a manifold.

Comment: For that, the book by Kodaira (deformation of complex structure) would be a possible reference?

Comment: @John: Thanks for that reference. I already knew it, but somehow I don't find it easy to read. I have the impression that it is explained in old-fashioned language or style.